# How to copy HDC content in WinGDI / C++

Tags: c++

I need do copy `HDC` content but my code is not working - any ideas why? Everything is well until I'm trying to copy between `HDC` objects. It seems that bits goes nowhere. I'm new to GDI programming.

I'm not sure how `SelectObject` should work here.

```
PAINTSTRUCT ps;
HDC paintDC = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
HDC imageDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(paintDC);
HDC bufferDC = ::CreateCompatibleDC(paintDC);

BITMAPINFO bitmapInfo;
memset ( &bitmapInfo, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER) );
bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
int scanLines = GetDIBits(imageDC,      // handle to DC
                          m_bitmap,         // handle to bitmap
                          0,                // first scan line to set
                          0,                // number of scan lines to copy
                          NULL,             // array for bitmap bits
                          &bitmapInfo,      // bitmap data buffer
                          DIB_RGB_COLORS ); // RGB or palette index

// Paint the bitmap image.
HBITMAP pOldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject( imageDC, m_bitmap );
int width = bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biWidth;
int height = bitmapInfo.bmiHeader.biHeight;

// Copy imageDC to bufferDC
BitBlt(bufferDC, 0, 0,
        width, height,
        imageDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY) ;   


BitBlt(paintDC, 0, 0,
       width, height, 
       imageDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
SelectObject(imageDC, pOldBitmap);
```

Comment: Usually it is easier to help if you describe *how* your code is not working. Is the output unexpected? If so, what do you expect for a given input? Are you getting any errors or warnings? Do you not enter a code block that you expect to enter? "Not working" and "goes nowhere" is to vague for diagnosis.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd183402(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

When you call `CreateCompatibleDC` function it'll create so called "memory DC" object. Memory DC doesn't have any image data attached to it by default (in fact id does, 1x1 monochrome bitmap, which is not what you want).

You do select a bitmap object for your `imageDC`, but you don't select any bitmap object for your `bufferDC`, that's why "bits go nowhere".

Create a `HBITMAP` object for your `bufferDC` (you can use `CreateCompatibleBitmap` for this) and select it for your `bufferDC` before performing any blits into it.

Remember one thing: `DC` object is an interface to something you can paint on, it doesn't contain any bitmap data itself.